# expressionengine wygwam content (links) break when included in form field

Tags: ee2, pixelandtonic, wygwam

using the EE "email to friend" form, I need to include the contents of a WYGWAM field in a hidden form field. here's what that looks like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="message[]" value="{title}{product_description}" />
```

the {product_description} field is WYGWAM content and contains links. the quotes in the links (`<a href="..."`) are breaking the formatting of the page because the browser reads the first href=" quote as the closing quote for the hidden field value. it's a quick fix to just change the hidden field attributes to single quotes but then it breaks the formatting if the {product_description} contains single quotes...

what's the best way to avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to strip all HTML from that content, and convert the quotes to entities. That email is going to be sent as plain text by the Tell-A-Friend form, so you'll need to remove all the HTML anyway.

Take a look at [CE String](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ce-string) - worth the small investment. You'd do something like this:

```
{exp:ce_str:ing removehtml htmlentities}{title}{product_description}{/exp:ce_str:ing}
```

Or, enable PHP in your template (on output):

```
<?php echo strip_tags(htmlentities("{title}{product_description}")); ?>
```

Comment: is that the only way to strip HTML from that content? btw, the tell-a-friend form does send HTML emails!

Comment: Just updated my answer.

Comment: thank you. works nicely. and I bought CE String just in case :-)